# Reuse LWP:UserAgent?

Tags: perl, http, tcp, lwp

How do you optimally use LWP::UserAgent in perl?
If I need to make several http calls would I reuse the same object?
E.g.

```
my $browser = LWP::UserAgent->new;    
foreach my $url (@urls) {  
   my $response = $browser->get( $url );  
   # process response  
}
```

Or

```
foreach my $url (@urls) {  
   my $browser = LWP::UserAgent->new;    
   my $response = $browser->get( $url );  
   # process response  
}
```

It seems to me that the second version is inefficient as it would reopen the connection each time right? Any issues I should be aware of?

Comment: Either is fine, but considering that the time it takes to contact a website and receive a response is orders of magnitude greater than the time it takes to create an object, efficiency isn't really a significant concern.

Comment: Re. "the second version is inefficient as it would reopen the connection each time" Both versions will send a new `GET` request in each loop iteration, if that's what you mean by "reopen the connection."

Comment: @Miller:It is not about time to construct the object.But about reusing an existing connection which is not possible if I do `new` each time

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot:Both will send GET (or POST?) but over the same underlying connection (only in the first case?)

Comment: @jm666:Some urls are the same or at least to the same host

Comment: I don't undestand why answers were deleted, got downvoted and vote to close

Comment: @jm666:"Keep alive" is the default in HTTP1.1

Comment: If I want to make multiple POST HTTP calls with different payload, will the above approach of reusing LWP useragent create any problem?

Answer (score 2):

As Miller commented, your two code examples are not tremendously different in terms of efficiency. Both will send a new `GET` request over a new connection for each loop iteration, which is more significant than the cost of creating an object.

You can cache connections using the *experimental* module [`LWP::ConnCache`](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP%3a%3aConnCache):

```
use LWP::ConnCache;
use LWP::UserAgent;

my $cache = LWP::ConnCache->new;
$cache->total_capacity(10); # Cache up to 10 connections

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new(conn_cache => $cache);
# Alternatively, my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new(keep_alive => 10);

$ua->get('http://www.google.com');
$ua->get('http://www.google.com'); # Should reuse cached connection
```

Note that you can use the same `LWP::ConnCache` object in multiple `LWP::UserAgent`s.

Comment: I guess experimental means "beta"/use on your own risk?

Comment: The documentation says "This module is experimental. Details of its interface is [sic] likely to change in the future."

Comment: If I want to make multiple POST HTTP calls with different payload, will the above approach of reusing LWP useragent create any problem?